# Double conditional probability for events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$,  $A,B,C \in \mathcal{F}$ is it correct that

$$P(A|B,C)=P(A|B|C)$$

This follows from

$$P(A|B,C)=P(A,B,C)/P(B,C)=P(A,B|C)P(C)/[P(B|C)P(C)]=P(A,B|C)/P(B|C)$$

and since $P(\cdot|C)$ is a probability then

$$P(A,B|C)/P(B|C)=P(A|B|C)$$

is it correct? is it correct the notation  $P(A|B|C)$?

Comment: What does $P(A\mid B\mid C)$ mean?  I've never seen that syntax.  Recall, the syntax $\Pr(A\mid B)$ is the probability of $A$ occurring given that it is known that $B$ occurs.  There is a very clear meaning of what comes before the bar and what comes after the bar and it is defined for just one bar.  Two bars is invalid syntax.

Comment: It looks like you went and treated "$B\mid C$" as an event.  It is not.

Comment: Call $Q(\cdot)=P(\cdot |C)$ the conditional probability given $C$ which is a probability on $\mathcal{F}$, I can calculate $Q(A|B)=Q(A,B)/Q(B)$ and that  is $Q(A|B)=P(A|B|C))$. (I've never seen that too)

Comment: Do you think there is a mistake?

Comment: I think it is an abuse of notation and any way you attempt to validate or formalize the notation you will end up back at $\Pr(A\mid B\cap C)$ and you would be better off using traditional notation instead.